# Android Studio refuses to run app on devices that meets the required API level except Android R

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-11

I am trying to debug my application on an Android device (Tecno Camon Cx Air) running `Android 7.0` i.e. `API level 24`, but Android Studio keeps giving me this error:

```
04/27 17:37:29: Launching 'app' on TECNO TECNO CX Air.
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed: INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK
The application's minSdkVersion is newer than the device API level.
Retry
```

Just tried on API level 27,28,29, I got the same error.

This is my defaultConfig:

```
 compileSdkVersion "android-R"
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.instantweather"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion "R"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ...
```

Would appreciate any help on this ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is your emulator or the device you are testing. the error says the mind of your project is more than the emulator SDK version. for example, the phone you're trying to install is android 6.2 but your project mind is 7.0 so it won't run and install.

Comment: Yeah but the device runs on Android 7.0, i.e. API level 24. The minimum SDK version I set for the project is 21 that's Android 5.0 :(

Comment: so the answer is simple. you have a library attached to your project which that library has minSdk above your Android 7.0 emulator.

Comment: And if you are trying to fix it you have to open the Github profile of every single lib you had implemented and checked the minSdk of each and when you hade found the problem then change the library to another one.

Comment: Wow! Just tried on API levels 27, 28, 29 still the same error.

Comment: Try to clean and rebuild and remake the project and test again. Are you sure about the emulator API level? send the emulator config and your dependency implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to tools => android => sdk manager and click on Launch stand alone sdk manager hyperlink. This will open sdk manager outside android-studio, select the packages and download. You can continue to work on android-studio this way..

Comment: no, the problem is not he has not the API level, the problem is it says it is above the emulator SDK version that different story.

Comment: @ShamsulHusainAnsari the problem is that the app can't run on any other API level except 30, Android R